# Creating pattern from tikzpic

Tags: tikz-pic

I have a tile.tex (a separate file) that I call in my main document.

I want to do two things

1. Create a pattern of 3x5 by stitching together tile.tex. This means I will be calling tile.tex 15 times.
2. I need to control rotation of each tile. Since my tile is a square therefore I will be rotating it at only four angels 0,90,180,270.

what do I need to do in following code

> ```
> \begin{document}
> %-----------------------------
> \begin{frame}
> \frametitle{\color{blue}{Tile}}
> \begin{figure}
> \input{tile}
> \end{figure}
> \end{frame}
> %-----------------------------
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: compile the `tile.tex` inside an `standalone` class. This way you have a cropped pdf file with your tile. Then you can use `\includegraphics` to input and rotate it like you want.

Comment: but how do I create a grid of tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your tile into an `standalone.cls` document:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node[draw=red, thick, minimum size=2cm] {A};
\end{document}
```

Which produces and adjusted/cropped figure:

[image: Tile]

And include this `graphic` file as an image wherever you need. A `tabular` can be used to organize them into a grid with or without separation between columns and rows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My title}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{@{}c}}
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=0]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=90]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=180]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=270]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=0]{mytile} \\
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=0]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=90]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=180]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=270]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=0]{mytile} \\
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=0]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=90]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=180]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=270]{mytile} &
\includegraphics[origin=c,angle=0]{mytile} \\
\end{tabular}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: slide]

In case you use `TikZ` to define your figure it's possible to use other solutions to build an array of rotated images. One of them could be to define the main image as a `pic` and repeat it inside a `matrix` with no columns and row separation. Some examples are following. The original figure has been taken from [looking for Efficient alternative to my tikzpic code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416552/looking-for-efficient-alternative-to-my-tikzpic-code/416582#416582).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    myfigure/.pic={
        \fill[black] (0,0) rectangle ++(-1,-1);
        \fill[blue] (-1,0) rectangle ++(-3,-1);
        \fill[green] (-4,0)-- ++(-1,0)--++(1,-1)--cycle;
        \fill[blue] (0,-1) rectangle ++(-1,-3);
        \fill[green] (0,-4)-- ++(-1,0)--++(1,-1)--cycle;
        \fill[red] (-4,-1)-- ++(0,-3)--++(3,0)--cycle;
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt] (A) {
    \pic[rotate around={-90:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; & 
    \pic[rotate around={180:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; \\
    \pic{myfigure}; &   
    \pic[rotate around={90:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; \\}; 

\matrix[column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt, right=of A] (B){
    \pic[rotate around={90:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; &   
    \pic{myfigure}; \\ 
    \pic[rotate around={180:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; &  
    \pic[rotate around={-90:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; \\}; 

\matrix[column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt, below=of A]{
    \pic[rotate around={180:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; &  
    \pic[rotate around={90:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; \\ 
    \pic[rotate around={270:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; &  
    \pic[rotate around={0:(-2.5,-2.5)}]{myfigure}; \\}; 

\begin{scope}[shift={(10.5cm,-10.5cm)}]
    \pic at (0,0) {myfigure};
    \pic[rotate=90] at (0,-1) {myfigure};
    \pic[rotate=180] at (1,-1) {myfigure};
    \pic[rotate=270] at (1,0) {myfigure};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am unable to compile your code. I get error "unknown file mytile".  I have not worked with standalone before and I am unable to get an output from it that I can save as "myfile.pdf"

Comment: I am using overleaf.com for my work. It is because of the online editor. I cant get an output from my standalone doc that I can save as mytile.pdf

Comment: I need these tiles to be side by side with no space between them. how can we do this

Comment: Does my answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416582/1952 solve the question?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an adjusted tabular and matrices of pics.

Comment: using "pic"  is interesting and makes more sense to me. Thanks for your help. I might post additional comments here as I apply this to my ongoing "tile" project.

Comment: One question regarding "pic" solution. Is it possible to have a separate pic.tex (\tikzset{myfigure/.pic={ ...}} part of your code) in our directory which we can call in grid.tex (\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\matrix[column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt] (A) {...};\end{tikzpicture}\end{document} )

Comment: You can include in the preamble with `\input{pic}`.