# looking for Efficient alternative to my tikzpic code

Tags: tikz-pic

I have a tikzpicture that has repeated elements. Right now I am defining them individually. But I would like to have a code that defines one template-triangle whose dimensions I control (like I do in my example via p1,q1) and use rotation to control orientation.

(Please note that this example is just for the purpose of illustration. I want to build more complicated patterns using other shapes and would like to avoid using more libraries)

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphicx,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Gridline

\coordinate (x1) at (-4,+0);
\coordinate (x2) at (+0,-4);
\coordinate (x3) at (+4,+0);
\coordinate (x4) at (+0,+4);

\coordinate (k) at (+0,+0);
\coordinate (p1) at (+4,+0);  %Triangle variable 
\coordinate (q1) at (+0,+4);  %Triangle variable

%---------------------------------

\coordinate (G1) at ($(x1)+(x2)$);
\coordinate (G2) at ($(x3)+(x4)$);

\draw [step=0.5cm,draw=gray] (G1) grid (G2);
%\draw [fill=yellow,opacity=0.5] ($(x1)+(x4)$)--(G2)--($(x3)+(x2)$)--(G1);

%---------------------------------
\coordinate (a1) at (k);
\coordinate (b1) at (p1);
\coordinate (c1) at (q1);

\coordinate (C1) at ($(k)$);
\coordinate (B1) at ($(C1)+(k)+(c1)$);
\coordinate (A1) at ($(B1)-(b1)$);
\draw [fill=black] (A1)--(B1)--(C1)--cycle;

\coordinate (A2) at ($(C1)$);
\coordinate (B2) at ($(A2)+(k)-(c1)$);
\coordinate (C2) at ($(B2)+(k)+(b1)$);
\draw [fill=red] (A2)--(B2)--(C2)--cycle;

\coordinate (A3) at ($(C1)$);
\coordinate (B3) at ($(A3)+(k)-(b1)$);
\coordinate (C3) at ($(B3)+(k)-(c1)$);
\draw [fill=green] (A3)--(B3)--(C3)--cycle;

\coordinate (A4) at ($(C1)$);
\coordinate (B4) at ($(A4)+(k)+(b1)$);
\coordinate (C4) at ($(B4)+(k)+(c1)$);
\draw [fill=blue] (A4)--(B4)--(C4)--cycle;

%---------------------------------
\draw[white,opacity=1] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

**2nd Example**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Gridline

\coordinate (x1) at (-4,+0);
\coordinate (x2) at (+0,-4);
\coordinate (x3) at (+4,+0);
\coordinate (x4) at (+0,+4);

\coordinate (k) at (+0,+0);
\coordinate (p1) at (+1.75,+0); 
\coordinate (q1) at (+0,+1.75); 
\coordinate (r1) at (+4.5,+0); 
\coordinate (s1) at (+0,+4.5); 

%---------------------------------

\coordinate (G1) at ($(x1)+(x2)$);
\coordinate (G2) at ($(x3)+(x4)$);

\draw [step=0.5cm,draw=none] (G1) grid (G2);
\draw [fill=yellow] ($(x1)+(x4)$)--(G2)--($(x3)+(x2)$)--(G1);

%---------------------------------
\coordinate (a1) at (k);
\coordinate (b1) at (p1);
\coordinate (c1) at (q1);

\coordinate (A1) at ($(x1)+(x4)$);
\coordinate (B1) at ($(A1)+(k)+(b1)$);
\coordinate (C1) at ($(B1)+(k)-(c1)$);
\draw [fill=black] (A1)--(B1)--(C1)--cycle;

\coordinate (b2) at (r1);
\coordinate (c2) at (c1);

\coordinate (A2) at (B1);
\coordinate (B2) at ($(A2)+(k)+(b2)$);
\coordinate (C2) at ($(B2)+(a1)-(c2)$);
\coordinate (D2) at (C1);
\draw [fill=black] (A2)--(B2)--(C2)--(D2)--cycle;

\coordinate (b3) at (b1);
\coordinate (c3) at (c1);

\coordinate (A3) at (B2);
\coordinate (B3) at ($(A3)+(k)+(b3)$);
\coordinate (C3) at ($(B3)+(a1)-(c2)$);
\coordinate (D3) at (C2);
\draw [fill=black] (A3)--(B3)--(C3)--(D3)--cycle;

\coordinate (b4) at (b1);
\coordinate (c4) at (s1);

\coordinate (A4) at (C2);
\coordinate (B4) at ($(A4)+(k)+(b4)$);
\coordinate (C4) at ($(B4)+(k)-(c4)$);
\coordinate (D4) at ($(C4)+(k)-(b4)$);
\draw [fill=black] (A4)--(B4)--(C4)--(D4)--cycle;

\coordinate (A5) at (D4);
\coordinate (B5) at ($(A5)+(k)+(b1)$);
\coordinate (C5) at ($(B5)+(k)-(c1)$);
\draw [fill=black] (A5)--(B5)--(C5)--cycle;

\coordinate (A6) at (C1);
\coordinate (B6) at ($(C1)+(k)-(s1)$);
\coordinate (C6) at (A5);
\draw [fill=black] (A6)--(B6)--(C6)--cycle;

%---------------------------------

\draw[white,opacity=1] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (current bounding box.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: your code is not compilable. missing are some libraries ...

Comment: Didn't know that there were tikz libraries `graphicx` or `graphics`, but thanks for loading `calc`... These are very different examples in that the first one is really very repetative in an obvious way but the second is less so... so you may want to split this question into two.

Comment: one problem on question please ...

Comment: i posted 2nd example because I am looking for general solution. Do u want me to post this 2nd example as a separate Q?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best `tikz` style to handle this, but works even without the missing libraries from your example.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 

\newcommand{\tri}[1]{%
    \draw[#1] (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tri{fill=black}
\tri{fill=red,rotate=90}
\tri{fill=green,rotate=180}
\tri{fill=blue,rotate=270}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you ever hibernate? (+1)

Comment: @marmot :) I'm actually on my way to do that now . In the mean time you can deal with all the tikz questions  - have fun!

Answer (score 3):

May be you can consider to use `pics`. You can use them to define a complex tikz figure and reuse it. It's possible to define them with arguments or even change some properties when they are finally drawn.

Following code show two examples with your figures. `mytriangle` defines a square triangle with origin in one vertex with three arguments: filling color and length of two sides. The second example defines the "complex" image.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    pics/mytriangle/.style n args={3}{
        code={
            \fill[#1] (0,0)--++(0,#2)--++(#3,0)--cycle;
        }
    },
    myfigure/.pic={
        \fill[black] (0,0) rectangle ++(-1,-1);
        \fill[blue] (-1,0) rectangle ++(-3,-1);
        \fill[green] (-4,0)-- ++(-1,0)--++(1,-1)--cycle;
        \fill[blue] (0,-1) rectangle ++(-1,-3);
        \fill[green] (0,-4)-- ++(-1,0)--++(1,-1)--cycle;
        \fill[red] (-4,-1)-- ++(0,-3)--++(3,0)--cycle;
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a/\c in {0/red,90/green,180/blue,270/black}
    \pic[rotate=\a] at (0,0) {mytriangle={\c}{2}{2}};

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\foreach \a/\c in {0/red,90/green,180/blue,270/black}
    \pic[rotate=\a] at (0,0) {mytriangle={\c}{1}{1.8}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\foreach \a/\c in {0/red,90/green,180/blue,270/black}
    \pic[rotate=\a] at (0,0) {mytriangle={\c}{1.5}{1}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a in {30,120,210,300}
    \pic[rotate=\a] at (\a:-1cm) {myfigure};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\foreach \X/\Col in{1/red,2/green,3/black,4/blue}
{
\coordinate (x\X) at ({-90*\X}:4);
\draw[fill=\Col] (x\X) -- +({-90*(\X-1)}:4) -- (O) -- cycle;
}

%Gridline
\coordinate (G1) at ($(x1)+(x2)$);
\coordinate (G2) at ($(x3)+(x4)$);
\draw [step=0.5cm,draw=gray] (G1) grid (G2);
\draw[white,opacity=1] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is going to work for triangles only. I added another example to make my point. answer by samcarter makes a template and reuses it. Thats more close to what I am looking for